# Add element to a list of objects in asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im creating a simple blog using MVC and entity framework.

These are my two classes:

```
public class BlogPost
    {
        public int BlogPostID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Post { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    }

public class Comments
    {
        public int CommentsID { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public int BlogPostID { get; set; }    
    }
```

Now, in my view, I display a Blogpost and i would like the user to be able to leave a comment, I imagin that the best way to do this is to create a beginform. This is what i have got:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "BlogPosts", new { blogid = @Model.BlogPostID }, FormMethod.Post))
{

     @Html.TextBoxFor() <---How do i acess the "Author"-property in comments?
     @Html.TextAreaFor() <---How do i acess the "Comment"-property in comments?

    <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
}
```

When the above problems are sorted out i´ll use this method to add the comment to the db:

```
public ActionResult AddComment(int blogid, Comments model)
        {

            BlogPost blogPost = db.BlogPosts.Find(blogid);

            blogPost.Comments.Add(model);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Does this seem like a good way to go about a task like this or am i maybe missing something fundamental?
Thans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Partial view for adding comment the model for partial view will be *Comments* type

Now put below razor in your partial view

```
@model Comments

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "BlogPosts", new { blogid = @Model.BlogPostID }, FormMethod.Post))
{

     @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Author) 
     @Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.Comment) 

    <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
}
```

Lets call this partial view AddComment.cshtml

Now in the blog post view add this partial view at the bottom like ,

```
@Html.Partial("AddComment",new Comments())
```

Comment: If it works for you , mark as answer :) , let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Didnt works as i hoped the @Html.Partial got hit i got this error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.BlogPost_19DBFxxxxxxxxxE7DE2250882D7CADC8BBBE90B598B57372FFF801A', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SQL.Models.Comments'.

Comment: Use this @Html.Partial("AddComment",new Comments()) , see the edited version.

Comment: Append "in Asp.Net MVC" to question.